# Laravel sibling attribute base validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, lumen

I have an array of attributes in my payload as follow:

```
{
    "courier_code" : "shipadelivery",
    "rule" : [ 
                {
                    "attribute" : "day",
                    "operator" : "eq",
                    "value" : "tue"
                }
            ],
    "is_active" : true,
    "priority" : 2
}
```

here what i need to validate is if the attribute is day then the value should be in `['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']` and the operator should be `eq`

How should i do the validation using the exising attribut params. I already did the validation for this not examine the attribute as follow

```
        $days = 'mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun';
        $rules = [
            'courier_code' => 'required|exists:shipment_companies,code',
            'is_active' => 'required|boolean',
            'priority' => 'required|integer',
            'rule' => 'required',
            'rule.*.attribute' => 'required',
            'rule.*.attribute' => 'required|in:'.$attributes,
            'rule.*.value' => 'required',
            'rule.*.operator' => 'required|in:'.$operators,
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditiosn to add rules dynamically to rules array

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$rules = [
    'courier_code' => 'required|exists:shipment_companies,code',
    'is_active' => 'required|boolean',
    'priority' => 'required|integer',
    'rule' => 'required',
    'rule.*.attribute' => 'required',
    'rule.*.operator' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in($operators),
    ],
];

if($request->filled('key-to-check') && $request->input('key-to-check') == 'day'){
    $rules['rule.*.value'] = 'required|in:'.implode(',', $attributes);
}
```

Because is an array you can run a loop:

```
foreach($request->input('rule') as $key => $value){
        $rule_key = 'rule.'.$key.'.value';

        if($value['attribute'] == 'day'){
            $rules[$rule_key] = 'required|in:'.$days;
        }else{
            $rules[$rule_key] = 'required';
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no @Froxz this is something different from your answer, my case is if attribute attribute is day then i want to check the value attribute should be in the array i mentioned above and throw the validation exception

Comment: @nifCody I'm glad my answer helped! Thank you